# What about using ORM tools in Final Year Project

Tags: entity-framework, orm

**Can i use ORM tools in my Final Year Project of Computer Science?**

I am developing a web based application in ASP .NET, so i want to know can i use such things like Entity Framework or Linq to object etc..

Because these tools/ frameworks creates Model classes automatically and the only thing left is to created GUI and bind using LINQ or Lambda...

the other option is to use traditionally approach write each and every class of BAL and DAL...

Comment: This seems like a question to ask your adviser, not a technical programming community that has a lot of opinions on either side of that fence. If you WANT to use an ORM and know its pluses and minuses, ask the adviser with those facts in hand. If not, then don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would. Tell your adviser that these tools are commonly used in real-life production scenarios.
Also, using Entity Framework does not imply generating the model automatically.
If you're allowed to, and interested, use Entity Framework and tangle with the code first approach and LINQ-to-entities.

Good luck.